# Does a Javascript self executing function work like a compiled program

Tags: javascript, function

Does a Javascript self executing function work like a compiled program. I.e can you declare some function after a named anonymous function within a self executing function and have the named anonymous function locate the other function at runtime? I.e why does the following work?

I'd thought that you could not hoist named anonymous functions as they are only created during runtime so perhaps the self executing function "compiles" the code to make the named anonymous function available to the function that calls it!!

```
(function(){
    var myFunc = function(){
        var bar = "Bar";
        return myFunc2() + bar;
    }

    function myFunc2(){
        return "Foo ";
    }

})()
```

or even

```
(function(){
    function myFunc(){
        var bar = "Bar";
        return myFunc2() + bar;
    }

    var myFunc2 = function(){
        return "Foo ";
    }

    window.fooBar = myFunc();

})()

console.log(fooBar);
```

Comment: No this doesn't have anything to do with the ability to "locate" certain functions. Non-anonymous functions in the current scope can be located from anywhere inside this scope. Only "named anonymous" functions can not be "forward-located" because you define them as variables which are only defined `after` assigning them

Comment: You might want to to consider the function terminology for future questions. Self-executing functions are generally referred to as _[Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)_, named anonymous functions are generally just called _function expressions_, and non-anonymous functions are _function declarations_.

Comment: @uws : I can argue with your statement. I've seen Self-executing functions been referred to as IIFE. But this is really wrong. Self executing function is actually recursion, and had nothing to do with IIFE.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that people refer to self-executing functions when they _mean_ IIFEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular example works because `myFunc2` is never called because `myFunc` is never called.

In general though, the normal rules for JS scope, hoisting and timing apply:

A variable must be populated before you *use* it, not before you define a function that will use it when called.

Comment: On top of that, any call to `myFunc` or `myFunc2` outside the anonymous function will throw an error.

Comment: "A variable must be populated before you use it, not before you define a function that will use it when called."   That's such a good answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
    var myFunc = function(){
        var bar = "Bar";
        return myFunc2() + bar;
    }

    function myFunc2(){
        return "Foo ";
    }

})()
```

After some hoisting this becames:

```
(function(){
    var myFunc;

    function myFunc2(){
        return myFunc2() + bar;
    }

    myFunc = function(){
        var bar = "Bar";
        return "Foo ";
    }
})()
```

And actually this will work if you call myFunc(); and log the returned value from myFunc2 you will get Foo Bar.

When hoisting named anonymous functions(which is actually function expression), only
var myFunc (= undefined); is hoisted. Then the assignment stay at the same level.

Also you cant refer this function as self execution function(because self executed function is actually recursion). This is Immediately Invoked Function Expressions.

And @Quentin said the rest: A variable must be populated before you use it, not before you define a function that will use it when called.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see what actually happens in your code.

1.you have a function that performs a variable assignment:
    var myFunc = ;

2.you declare a function. (But don't yet invoke it)

3.you assign myFunc to window.foobar.

4.And you invoke the function you were defining.

Now, these steps happen:

1. myFunc gets a function as its value.
2. myFunc2 gets defined.
3. window.foobar gets the result of calling myFunc().
   so what happens is, myFunc() **returns the result of  invoking myFunc2()** and appends its result to bar.

Thus, the value of window.foobar will be "foobar".

(no, this is not how compiled programs work)